# python3's adjust_text is moving text badly

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have overlapping text from my script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
x = [12,471,336,1300]
y = [2,5,4,11]
z = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
im = plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, cmap = "gist_rainbow", alpha = 0.5)
plt.colorbar(im)
texts = []
texts.append(plt.text(783, 7.62372448979592, 'TRL1'))
texts.append(plt.text(601, 6.05813953488372, 'CFT1'))
texts.append(plt.text(631, 4.28164556962025, 'PTR3'))
texts.append(plt.text(665, 7.68018018018018, 'STT4'))
texts.append(plt.text(607, 5.45888157894737, 'RSC9'))
texts.append(plt.text(914, 4.23497267759563, 'DOP1'))
texts.append(plt.text(612, 7.55138662316476, 'SEC8'))
texts.append(plt.text(766, 4.1264667535854, 'ATG1'))
texts.append(plt.text(681, 3.80205278592375, 'TFC3'))
plt.show()
```

which shows overlapping text:
[image]

however, when I add `adjust_text`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
x = [12,471,336,1300]
y = [2,5,4,11]
z = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
im = plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, cmap = "gist_rainbow", alpha = 0.5)
plt.colorbar(im)
data = [
    (783, 7.62372448979592, 'TRL1'),
    (601, 6.05813953488372, 'CFT1'),
    (631, 4.28164556962025, 'PTR3'),
    (665, 7.68018018018018, 'STT4'),
    (607, 5.45888157894737, 'RSC9'),
    (914, 4.23497267759563, 'DOP1'),
    (612, 7.55138662316476, 'SEC8'),
    (766, 4.1264667535854, 'ATG1'),
    (681, 3.80205278592375, 'TFC3')
]

texts = [plt.text(x, y, l) for x, y, l in data]
adjust_text(texts)
plt.savefig('adjust.text.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0.1)
```

the labels are shifted to the lower left corner, making them useless, instead of just a little overlapped.

I am following clues from `adjust_text(texts)` as suggested by the below two links,

[How to adjust text in Matplotlib scatter plot so scatter points don't overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583615/how-to-adjust-text-in-matplotlib-scatter-plot-so-scatter-points-dont-overlap)

and https://adjusttext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html

I get this:[image]

how can I get `adjust_text` to fix the overlapping labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you call [`adjust_text`](https://adjusttext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#adjustText.adjust_text) but doing it like below, works for me :

```
# top of the code..

adjust_text(texts)

plt.show()
```

And BTW, you could also simplify the way you make the `texts` list :

```
data = [
    (783, 7.62372448979592, 'TRL1'),
    (601, 6.05813953488372, 'CFT1'),
    (631, 4.28164556962025, 'PTR3'),
    (665, 7.68018018018018, 'STT4'),
    (607, 5.45888157894737, 'RSC9'),
    (914, 4.23497267759563, 'DOP1'),
    (612, 7.55138662316476, 'SEC8'),
    (766, 4.1264667535854, 'ATG1'),
    (681, 3.80205278592375, 'TFC3')
]

texts = [plt.text(x, y, l) for x, y, l in data]
```

[image]

Comment: could you paste your entire code? I can't get what you wrote to work

Comment: I fixed it now, the problem was that I was using adjustText version 0.8, updating to 1.0.4 fixed the problem